# how to change geolocation with selenium with coordinates from json file?

Tags: json, selenium, geolocation

I am trying to change geolocation with selenium with coordinates from a json file. But the code I use does not seem to work and I dont understand why. Here is the code I used:

```
f = open("accounts.json",)
datas = json.load(f)

def project(data):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", {
        "latitude": data["latitude"],
        "longitude": data["longitude"],
        "accuracy": 100
    })

    driver.get(data["email_link"])
for data in datas:
    tinder(data)
```

and here is the content of the json file:

```
[
  {
      "latitude": "40.7142700",
      "longitude": "-74.0059700",
      "number": "8597108226",
      "number_link": "https://temp-number.com/inbox.php?country=United%20States&no=18597108226&in=US",
      "email_link": "https://emailfake.com/tindertest@ucyeh.com",
      "full_email_link": "emailfake.com/tindertest@ucyeh.com",
      "email_name": "tindertest@ucyeh.com"
  }
]
```

The error occurs in the 2 lines for latitude and longitude inside my project(data) function, and if I input the values directly instead of getting them from the json file it works. but using the data["latitude"] as an input value does not work. Can anyone please help me figure out what the error here might be?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's to late for ansewer any way
try this

```
dates=[
  {
      "latitude": "40.7142700",
      "longitude": "-74.0059700",
      "number": "8597108226",
      "number_link": "https://temp-number.com/inbox.php?country=United%20States&no=18597108226&in=US",
      "email_link": "https://emailfake.com/tindertest@ucyeh.com",
      "full_email_link": "emailfake.com/tindertest@ucyeh.com",
      "email_name": "tindertest@ucyeh.com"
  }
]
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", {
        "latitude": dates[0]["latitude"],
        "longitude": dates[0]["longitude"],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.